# How to get element by name with $key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

PHP

```
  //Here is my html for qty

       <p>Qty : <input type="number"  value="" name="qty<?php echo $key ?>   onChange="findTotal()"/>
```

JS function

```
        function findTotal() {
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
      ...

        document.getElementById('result').value = decimalPlaces(tot, 2);

        }
```

**My qty name needs key for post array. How do I get name inside js function to calculate quantities?**

Comment: you could put the qty inside value and then it would be var qty = myclass.val()

Comment: if php code does not generate the js code you are in trouble.
You can resort to `docment.querySelectorAll('input[name^=qty]')` to have an array of components with name starting with qty but I do not see how to go further

Comment: @Eineki Did you mean in funtion getTotal() : I put like this: var arr =document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=qty]'); ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/Lw30j9tv/1/

Comment: @Jenny what are you trying to obtain, A sum of quantities (maybe times price) in a field with id result?

Comment: @Eineki  ye When I hit quantity of each items it will be sent to js function to calculate total cost like quantities times price including with their own rules

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`document.querySelector("input['name^='qty']").value`

if you don't have jQuery.

This will select an `input` with `name` attribute starting with "qty". If you have multiple inputs which match the criteria you can select them all using

`document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='qty']")`

which will return a `NodeList`. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
  var myVar = document.getElementsByTagName("somename");
  //do something else
```

If you are using jquery

```
value = $( "input[name^='qtd']" ).val();
//it will pick the input wich name starts with 'qtd'
```

Comment: Where I can add jquery to get value of qty in side findTotal()? Thanks

Comment: you have to import jquery script file in your project to use it.
if you are using just javascript you can do.
var = document.querySelectorAll("[name^=qty]")

Comment: Yes it will work, if you use the selector in javascript to get the element.

Answer (score 0):

In pure DOM, you could use getElementsByTagName to grab all input elements, and loop through the resulting array. Elements with name starting with 'qty' get pushed to another array:

```
var eles = [];
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].name.indexOf('qty') == 0) {
        eles.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't query the element by the name attribute's value. I'm not sure what's the purpose of the key and why you need it in the findTotal method, but here's an example:

```
<p>Qty : <input type="number" value="" name="qtyMyKey" onChange="findTotal(event)" /></p>

  <script>
    function findTotal(e) {

      var inputEl = e.target,
        inputName = inputEl.getAttribute('name'),
        myKey;

      if (typeof inputName === 'string') {
        myKey = inputName.replace('qty', '');
      }

      console.log(myKey);

      //var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
      //document.getElementById('result').value = decimalPlaces(inputEl.value(), 2);
    }

  </script>
```

---

Here's the [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw30j9tv/2/).

Comment: But my name has php $key in side ?